# Unable to setup EasyClangComplete for Sublime Text

Tags: c++, plugins, autocomplete, sublimetext3, clang-complete

Recently, I shifted to Sublime text editor from VS Code. In VS code I use C/C++ extension by Microsoft for C++ autocompletion.

I go through the steps given in https://github.com/niosus/EasyClangComplete.

I am able to do the first 2 steps but step 3 that is **Configure your compiler flags and include folders** confused me. How can I be able to successfully install this plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step1**: To install EasyClangComplete, first you need to have Package Control. Then press following

```
CTRL+Shift+P for Windows
CMD+Shift+P  for MacOS
```

Now search Package Control: Install Package and press enter. Then search EasyClangComplete and install it.

**Step2**: Need to install Clang

```
Ubuntu  : sudo apt-get install clang
MacOS   : By default installed. You are all set!
Windows : install the latest release from clang website.
```

To check if it successfully installed

```
clang --version
```

**Step3**: Configure your compiler flags and include folders.

For this step, you just need to create 2 empty files in your project root folder.

```
CMakeLists.txt
compile_commands.json
```

Now, restart sublime text editor and auto-completion feature will work successfully.

### If this doesn't work, you need to do 1 more step.

Go to Package Setting > EasyClangComplete > Settings. Now add following code in file "EasyClangComplete.sublime-settings"

```
{
 "common_flags" : [
    // some example includes
    "-I/usr/include",
    "-I$project_path/src",
    // this is needed to include the correct headers for clang
    "-I/usr/lib/clang/$clang_version/include",
    // For simple projects, you can add a folder where your current file is
    "-I$file_path",
  ],
}
```

Comment: Where is `EasyClangComplete.sublime-settings` located?